# embedded frameworkのプロジェクトをClean Build Folderすると毎回エラーになる

Tags: swift, xcode, framework

## はじめに

embedded frameworkに挑戦しています。
コンパイルが通り実行もできたのですが、
`Clean Build Folder`すると毎回エラーになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 再現可能なプロジェクトの場所

Xcodeのプロジェクトファイルも関係すると思いますので、
ソースコード自体を載せることにあまり意味がないように感じますので、
プロジェクト全体を持つGitHubへのリンクを置きます。

https://github.com/shingo-nakanishi/embedded-framework

↑この中のHogeフォルダです。

## エラー内容

エラー内容は

> undefined symbol: method descriptor for FooKit.Foo__allocating__init() -> FooKit.Foo

といったものが主です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 一旦は解決するが...

おそらく
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687105/framework-not-found-in-xcode
が解決策になると考え、

一度、本プロジェクトの
`Embedded Binaries` から全てのembedded frameworkを「-」ボタンで削除し、「+」ボタンで追加し、複数回Xcodeの実行ボタンを押すと正常に実行されます。

（おそらくXcodeの実行ボタンを押す回数は関係なく、「+」ボタンを押した結果が反映されるのに時間がかかっている？）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### しかしもう一度、Clean Build Folderするとエラー

上記の通り、「削除＆追加」をすると正常に動きだしましたが、
もう一度Clean Build Folderするとまた同じエラーになります。
その都度、「削除＆追加」をすればよいのですが、あまりにも手間です。

なにかやり方が間違っているのでしょうか？
それとも、Clean Build Folderは基本的にできなくなってしまうのでしょうか？

## 念の為に関係しているソースを載せます

「はじめに」に書いたとおりあまりソースコード自体は関係ない気がしますが、関係しているソースコードも載せておきます。

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import FooKit
import BarKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(Foo().f)
        print(Bar().f)
        print(Bar().b)
    }
}
```

**Foo**

```
import Foundation

open class Foo {
    public init() {}
    public let f = "F"
}
```

**Bar**

```
import Foundation
import FooKit

public class Bar: Foo {
    public let b = "B"
}
```

【再掲】プロジェクト全体のコードは次のリンクです
https://github.com/shingo-nakanishi/embedded-framework

### 参考にしたサイト

embedded frameworkを作成したときに参考にしたサイトを念の為、載せておきます
https://qiita.com/edm/items/4cda53320dfa0858d542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target `BarKit`の Target Dependenciesに、継承元の`FooKit`を指定してないためだと思います。

それぞれが並列的にBuildされる際に`Bar`は`Foo`を継承していますから、Target `BarKit`をBuildするためには`FooKit`が必要です。この依存関係の指定が欠けているためです。